# Calculate MOSFET Forward Voltage Drop

Tags: mosfet, source, voltage, rdson

I'd like to better understand how to calculate the voltage drop between the Drain and the Source of a FET.

As an example, say we have a [MDD1902](http://www.yztdz.com/Down/pdf/MDD1902.pdf) N-channel FET. How would I determine the maximum voltage drop that can occur over Vds if the max drain current is 5A, max temperature is 75C, and Vgs is typically 12V?

Comment: R(DS on) * Current, all of which are infos you have.

Comment: But the Rds(on) can change based off temperature. Right?

Comment: and the given Rds(on) is when Vgs is 10V not 12V. So that equation isn't as straight forward. Right?

Comment: Yes, but the info is on the datasheet you provided.

Comment: Diodes have a **forward** voltage (drop). Since mosfets have a (parasitic) body diode, it's confusing to write forward voltage drop (in your title) when you're refereing to the drop due to Rds(on). Better remove the "forward" from the title, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You estimate it with the charts on page 3 of your datasheet.  Specifically figures 3 and 4.

Figure 3 is telling us that the on resistance at 75 C is 1.4 times what it is at 25 C (the y-axis is normalized).

[image]

Figure 4 is telling us the resistance between gate and source is going to be around 20 mΩ at 12 V.

[image]

$$20 mΩ * 1.4 = 28 mΩ$$

Using Ohm's law:  $$5 A * 0.028 Ω =  0.14 V$$

Keep in mind these are rough estimates based on the charts.

Comment: How do you know that Figure 3's y-axis is a factor of 1.4 and not just 1.4mOhms? I assumed it to be 1.4mOhms which confused me further. @evildemonic

Comment: @Tim51 Because it says it is "normalized".  Note that the line crosses '1.0' at exactly 25 C.  Also, 1.4 mΩ doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that "normalized" meant that it was dimensionless. @evildemonic

Comment: Is there anything else that can affect the forward voltage drop/ Rds(on)? Or is this the complete process for determining the forward voltage drop across a FET in a circuit? @evildemonic

Comment: For DC and low frequency, that is it.

Comment: Great, thank you for taking the time to explain this to me! Much appreciated! @evildemonic I noticed most people are just saying Rds(on) x Drain current. Is that a correct approach? That seems to leave out temperature variations.

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: They didn't read your question carefully enough.  Rds(on) is always affected by temperature.  Many (most?) applications this can be neglected because you don't care too much about the exact value of Rds(on) or the current is so low you are operating very close to room temperature...so the simpler equation is often used.

Comment: I also noticed the normalized curve is charted while Vgs = 10V. Does that have an affect here when the Vgs in this example is 12V? Or is the difference something you have to accept in order to get a estimate? @evildemonic

Comment: Just to make sure I've got the concept down I have performed the same calculation with a TPH4R008NH,L1Q and determined its Rds(on) would be ~5mOhms at 75C from figure  8.6. Then just applied Ohms law to get the drop. 5A x 5mR = 25mV drop. @evildemonic

Comment: @Tim51 Yeah, you got it...probably slightly less than 5 mΩ, but a good estimate.

Comment: @Tim51 Yes, that chart is at Vgs = 10 V, and the values will be slightly different than at 12 V.  The difference is very very small, however, and can be ignored.

Comment: Awesome thanks again! @evildemonic

Answer (score 0):

Voltage drop will be Rdson * Ids.